# Response type in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, response

I would like to use my form partial for html and js requests. For the second i have to put `:remote => true` into `form_for` tag.

Is it possible to read the response type (html, js, ...) and use this as condition in a view?

Comment: What about the URL format? Is it `*.js` if js is the response type?

Comment: thanks for the hint. i think i will use `request.xhr?`.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, this example of [**`respond_to`**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to)'s usage should help you. And for complement: There is a [**Discussion in Ruby Forum**](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/150877) you can take advantage.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { #Magic goes here }
```

You can also check before the `respond_to` block by calling `request.xhr?`. But be aware with the `respond_to` block. AJAX **can** respond with html (i.e `$.ajax({dataType: 'html'})`)